# Time complexity of loop

Tags: c, time-complexity, complexity-theory

I'm unsure as to the complexity of the following block of C:

```
int i = 0, j = 1;
for ( i = 0; i < n * n; i += j )
{
    O1();
    j += 2;
}
```

where O1 is a function that obviously takes constant time to execute. Now, I am aware that loops whose counter gets increased by a constant amount every iteration generally have a complexity of `O(sqrt(n))`, but is this the case here as well? Or is it `O(sqrt(n^2))`, that is `O(n)`?

Thanks

Comment: Your variable i follows an arithmetic progession : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression

Comment: Actually, it's an _arithmetic series_, or a _quadratic sequence_.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I am aware that loops whose counter gets increased by a constant amount every iteration generally have a complexity of O(sqrt(n))

That's false.  A loop whose counter gets increased by a constant amount every iteration is O(N).

A loop whose counter increases by an amount that increases linearly on each iteration is O(sqrt(N)).

In this case, `N` here is `n * n`, as that's what your loop is looping until, so that simple replacement tells you that, yes, the operation is O(sqrt(n^2)) or O(n).

Comment: Thanks for the correction and confirming my suspicion. What about if the counter increased geometrically instead?

Comment: Please include the proof ! i = S(n) = n*(n+1) / 2

Comment: @w.kovacs Then you have an inversely geometric number of operations performed.

Comment: @Servy How do you express that in Big O notation?

Comment: @w.kovacs That would be logarithms.

Answer (score 3):

> I am aware that loops whose counter gets increased by a constant amount every iteration generally have a complexity of O(sqrt(n))

**Nope!** That is not true. Take for instance this loop

```
for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
```

Its variable `i` is increasing by constant amount, i.e `1`. But the complexity of this loop is `O(n)`

---

If you see the series closely, the values `i` will get are

```
0, 3, 8, 15, 24, 35, ...
```

Its an arithmetic series. It can also be written as

```
0^2 - 1, 1^2 - 1, 2^2 - 1, 3^2 - 1, 4^2 - 1, 5^2 - 1, 6^2 - 1, ...
```

---

Now the loop will run until `i` reaches `n^2`, (`i < n*n`)

So you can deduce from that, that the loop will run for `O(n)`.

Therefore the complexity is `O(n)`

Answer (score 1):

It is O(n), because the loop will iterate exactly `n` times.

On interation 1: the value of `i` would be `1 * 1 - 1` which is `0`

On interation 2: the value of `i` would be `2 * 2 - 1` which is `3`

On interation 3: the value of `i` would be `3 * 3 - 1` which is `8`

...

On interation n: the value of `i` would be `n * n - 1`. This causes the loop to terminate.

In summary, `i` grows fast enough to reach `n * n - 1` in `n` iterations.

Comment: It will *not* iterate exactly n times.  It *is* O(n), but there is a coefficient there.

Comment: @Servy, it will iterate exactly `n` times, you can verify that.